# What's the most straightforward way to copy an ArrayBuffer object?

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

I'm working with `ArrayBuffer` objects, and I would like to duplicate them. While this is rather easy with actual pointers and `memcpy`, I couldn't find any straightforward way to do it in Javascript.

Right now, this is how I copy my `ArrayBuffers`:

```
function copy(buffer)
{
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var output = new ArrayBuffer(buffer.byteLength);
    var outputBytes = new Uint8Array(output);
    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
        outputBytes[i] = bytes[i];
    return output;
}
```

Is there a prettier way?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`ArrayBuffer` is supposed to support `slice` (http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/) so you can try,

```
buffer.slice(0);
```

which works in Chrome 18 but not Firefox 10 or 11. As for Firefox, you need to copy it manually. You can monkey patch the `slice()` in Firefox because the Chrome `slice()` will outperform a manual copy. This would look something like,

```
if (!ArrayBuffer.prototype.slice)
    ArrayBuffer.prototype.slice = function (start, end) {
        var that = new Uint8Array(this);
        if (end == undefined) end = that.length;
        var result = new ArrayBuffer(end - start);
        var resultArray = new Uint8Array(result);
        for (var i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++)
           resultArray[i] = that[i + start];
        return result;
    }
```

Then you can call,

```
buffer.slice(0);
```

to copy the array in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: In Chrome (29 at the time of this comment), ArrayBuffer does not have a method named .slice, but .subarray(start [, end]) instead.  Not sure how it is in FF.

Comment: Looks like the spec changed since my answer was posed. I will work on updating it. `subarray()` is in the new standard in place of `slice()`.

Comment: Looking again at the spec, `ArrayBuffer` should have `slice()`. The typed arrays (such as `Uint8Array`) should have `subarray()`. The above is correct for `ArrayBuffer`.

Comment: Note that `subarray()` returns a new view on an existing buffer and does not actually copy the buffer.

Comment: Note the begin parameter of `slice()` is optional, so you can just simply `buffer.slice()`.

Answer (score 69):

I prefer the following method

```
function copy(src)  {
    var dst = new ArrayBuffer(src.byteLength);
    new Uint8Array(dst).set(new Uint8Array(src));
    return dst;
}
```

Comment: Seems like your answer is [fastest than the chosen one](http://jsperf.com/clone-float32array).

Comment: @Viclib, please note that you probably need to provide a fallback for IE.

Comment: Note additionally, that performance for different types may vary as well; from what I can remember Uint8 copies faster than Float32. I think the fastest was Int32; but then you have to have data properly padded. YMMV.

Comment: @Viclib Afaik, all of them.

Comment: @Gleno - Why is a fallback required for IE?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum because IE can't do anything!

Answer (score 38):

It appears that simply passing in the source dataview performs a copy:

```
var a = new Uint8Array([2,3,4,5]);
var b = new Uint8Array(a);
a[0] = 6;
console.log(a); // [6, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(b); // [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Tested in FF 33 and Chrome 36.

Comment: This is a great answer, and it seems cross-browser compatible. Thank you !

Comment: Indeed, this is much better than the accepted answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Something to note: `new Uint8Array(a.buffer)` does *not* copy the buffer. This can be useful depending on your needs. It also accepts optional `byteOffset` and `length` params when called with an ArrayBuffer. This is very similar to NodeJS's `Buffer.from(Buffer, byteOffset, length)` in Node v6.

Comment: For now it is the most fast way, thanx a lot! Who want to see it I made a bench http://jsben.ch/rkCpx (slow cases are disabled)

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... if it's the Uint8Array you want to slice (which logically, it should be), this may work.

```
 if (!Uint8Array.prototype.slice && 'subarray' in Uint8Array.prototype)
     Uint8Array.prototype.slice = Uint8Array.prototype.subarray;
```

Answer (score 2):

Faster and slightly more complicated version of chuckj's answer. Should use ~8x less copy operations on large Typed Arrays. Basically we copy as much 8-byte chunks as possible and then copy the remaining 0-7 bytes. This is especially useful in current version of IE, since it doesn't have slice method implemented for ArrayBuffer.

```
if (!ArrayBuffer.prototype.slice)
    ArrayBuffer.prototype.slice = function (start, end) {
    if (end == undefined) end = that.length;
    var length = end - start;
    var lengthDouble = Math.floor(length / Float64Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT); 
    // ArrayBuffer that will be returned
    var result = new ArrayBuffer(length);

    var that = new Float64Array(this, start, lengthDouble)
    var resultArray = new Float64Array(result, 0, lengthDouble);

    for (var i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++)
       resultArray[i] = that[i];

    // copying over the remaining bytes
    that = new Uint8Array(this, start + lengthDouble * Float64Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT)
    resultArray = new Uint8Array(result, lengthDouble * Float64Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);

    for (var i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++)
       resultArray[i] = that[i];

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This causes `ArrayBuffer length minus the byteOffset is not a multiple of the element size.` in Android stock browser.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap a `Buffer` around the `ArrayBuffer`.  This is shared memory and no copy is made.  Then create a new Buffer from the wrapping `Buffer`.  This will copy the data.  Finally get a reference to the new `Buffer`'s `ArrayBuffer`.

This is the most straighforward way I can find.  The most efficient?  Perhaps.

```js
const wrappingBuffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer)
const copiedBuffer = Buffer.from(wrappingBuffer)
const copiedArrayBuffer = copiedBuffer.buffer
```

Comment: Results in `Buffer is not defined` in both Firefox and Chrome...

Comment: Buffer is only in nodejs

Answer (score 0):

In some cases (like webaudio Audiobuffers) you only have a reference to the 2 arrays.
So if you have array1 as a float32Array and array2 as a float32Array,
you must do an element by element copy.

To do so you can use different methods.

```
            var ib=z.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
            var ob=z.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
```

this

```
            ib.forEach((chd,i)=>ob[i]=chd);
```

or this nicer and probably **faster**

```
            ob.set(ib);
```

That's because Array.set populates an existing array with multiple data (even from another array)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the operations above only do "shallow" copies. When working with workers and transferable arrays, you need to do a deep copy.

```
function copyTypedArray(original, deep){
    var copy;
    var kon = original.constructor;
    if(deep){
        var len = original.length;
        copy = new kon(len);
        for (var k=len; --k;) {
            copy[k] = original[k];
        }
    } else {
        var sBuf = original.buffer;
        copy = new kon(sBuf);
        copy.set(original);
    }
    return copy;
}
```

HINT (for the confused): Typed Arrays contain an ArrayBuffer, which can be obtained via the "buffer" property.

```
var arr = new Float32Array(8);
arr.buffer <-- this is an ArrayBuffer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the browser you can do:

```js
const copy = structuredClone(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

With some crafty usage of the spread operator, you can force a copy like so:

```
const newCopy = new Uint8Array(
  [... new Uint8Array(source)]
).buffer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the slice function of the ArrayBuffer

slice()

slice(start)

slice(start, end)

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me, you might be looking for how to copy memory from one WebAssembly module to another. Here's how:

```js
function copy_plugin_memory_to_host_memory(dest, src, len) {
    const plugin_data = new Uint8Array(plugin_memory.buffer, src, len);
    const host_data = new Uint8Array(host_memory.buffer, dest, len);
    host_data.set(plugin_data);
}
```

Where `host_memory` and `plugin_memory` are WebAssembly memory objects passed into two seperate WASM files. You'd want your host call `copy_plugin_memory_to_host_memory` as an imported functions when passing raw/complex data structures around.

```js
const host_memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({
    initial: 20,
    maximum: 200,
    shared: true,
});
const plugin_memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({
    initial: 20,
    maximum: 200,
    shared: false,
});
```